# Configure tab size in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, editors

It seems that by default the tab-size in the Overleaf editor is set to 4 spaces. I find this too big.

Is it possible to configure this value? I would prefer to set it to 2.

Comment: I found an open issue about this: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/198. So maybe this is a feature that just hasn't been implement yet?

Comment: Also related (but without definitive answer): https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/jvnrre/how_to_change_the_editor_indent_level_in_overleaf/

Comment: This sounds like a purely Overleaf-related issue and as such not really on-topic here.

Comment: @campa We have a Overleaf tag here. Is it written somewhere that overleaf questions are not on-topic here?

Comment: Overleaf questions are not per se off-topic, see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8045/82917, and the line separating which questions are and which are not is hard to draw. This being said, this question isn't related to typesetting and is as such _in my opinion_ off-topic. While you might get an answer here, I believe it's more likely to get one from the Overleaf support team.

Comment: @campa I see. I have tried contacting support. If I get an answer I'll post it here.